# Erro na leitura do JSON

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, python-2.7

Estou tentando em ler os JSONs de uma pasta e pegar os devidos valores, ja testei todos os JSONs para ver se eram validos.
A pasta com os JSONs se chama 'test'

```
for dirname, dirnames, filenames in os.walk('test'):
    for filename in filenames:
        with open(os.path.join(dirname,filename)) as fd:
            json_data = json.load(fd)
            print json_data
```

A ideia e percorrer toda a pasta e todos os arquivos, lendo-os e mostrando o conteudo. Porem ao executar recebo um:

> ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded

Este e um JSON:

```
{
    "test": "Search User 1",
    "url": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/user/1/?format=json",
    "status_code": 200,
    "method": "get"
}
```

Comment: @CesarMiguel pode me mandar o link de onde eu encontro como fazer esta formatacao que fizestes pra mim?

Comment: se reparares ao criar/editar uma pergunta/resposta tens um editor para poderes editar e manipular a tua questão, colocando texto como código ou citação. Não encontrei nenhum link que explica-se, mas basta explorares um pouco e já percebes. Deixo aqui também um link para veres (vale sempre a pena): http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1084/como-devemos-formatar-perguntas-e-respostas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como você está lendo de um arquivo, possivelmente o conteúdo é uma `string`, então `json.load` não vai funcionar. A outra coisa é que você está passando para o método `json.load` o descritor do arquivo, e não um JSON propriamente dito.

Utilize no lugar:

```
json_data = json.loads(fd.read())
```

[Leia mais aqui](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/json.html).

Comment: Obrigado, funcionou =D